# JQuery Select2 Item not found trigger

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, ui-select2

I would like to have a callback for my select2 fields. I'm trying to display all the item name on my select2 component. But if the user just typed in the name of the item and the item is not under any option of the select input then I would like to pop up a dialog informing them if they want to add this as new item. So I was wondering if there are any sort of callback for this function. Here's what I was thinking

```
$('select').select2({
    onSelect: function(item) {
         if (item == null || $(this).options == 0) {
         // A dialog will prompt saying would you like to add this item?
         }
    }
});
```

I know syntax for this is not correct but you can the idea right? I just want to know what is the callback to determine if an item type in the select2 is not existing or better yet I want a callback to be triggered if the user type in something that is not on the select2 options.

Comment: Is it `tag` or normal `select` option?

Comment: Its a tag. Although I made the attribute "TAG" to true but I can't find a callback for this

Comment: What version of `select2` you are using?

Comment: I'm using selec2 4.0 https://github.com/select2/select2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok here you go. Below are the 2 scenarios which works to some extent:

**Scenario 1:**

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/jnw96phd/6/)**

Enabled confirmation prompt only for click on the **newtag**

```
$('.select2').select2({
    tags: true,
    tokenSeparators: [",", " "],
    createTag: function (tag) {
        return {
            id: tag.term,
            text: tag.term,
            isNew : true
        };
    }
}).on("select2:select", function(e) {
    if(e.params.data.isNew){
        var r = confirm("do you want to create a tag?");
        if (r == true) {
$(this).find('[value="'+e.params.data.id+'"]').replaceWith('<option selected value="'+e.params.data.id+'">'+e.params.data.text+'</option>');
        }
        else
        {
            $('.select2-selection__choice:last').remove();
            $('.select2-search__field').val(e.params.data.text).focus()
        }
    }

});
```

**Scenario 2:**

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/qd17suhn/12/)**

Confirmation for both `click` and `space` but tag gets added to list:

```
$('.select2').select2({
    tags: true,
    tokenSeparators: [",", " "]
}).on("change", function(e) {
    var isNew = $(this).find('[data-select2-tag="true"]');
    if(isNew.length){
        var r = confirm("do you want to create a tag?");
        if (r == true) {
isNew.replaceWith('<option selected value="'+isNew.val()+'">'+isNew.val()+'</option>');        
        }
        else
        {
            $('.select2-selection__choice:last').remove();
            $('.select2-search__field').val(isNew.val()).focus()
        }
    }
});
```

> **You need to find some workaround for tag getting added in false case.**

Comment: This seems to solve some of my question. Although I had to modify something. But then again this is great. Thanks

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding..:)